# Xamarin Android Pass Data Between Fragments

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I create Android Project in Xamarin plugin for Visual Studio Community 2015. I have in my application 4 fragments and I switch in them by ViewPager which is navigated in ActionBar. In second and third tab, there are few fields (for second tab -> Name, Surname, Mail, Phone and for third -> description field). These fields are EditText. On last fragment there are fields (TextView) and I need to pass data from 2nd, 3rd to 4th fragment. These data is only string value.
I try to use this code:

```
public void OnTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        viewPager.CurrentItem = tab.Position;
        if (tab.Position == 0)
        {
            actionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.GalleryTab);
        } else if (tab.Position == 1)
        {
            actionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.DescriptionTab);
        } else if (tab.Position == 2)
        {
            actionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.ContactInfoTab);
        } else if (tab.Position == 3)
        {
            actionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.SummaryTab);
            nameContact.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                nameSummary.Text = e.Text.ToString();
            };                
        }
```

nameContact and nameSummary are properly initialized.

```
var nameContact = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.nameContactText);
var surnameContact = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.surnameContactText);

var nameSummary = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameSummary);
var surnameSummary = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.surnameSummary);
```

Can someone explain me how to send data between fragments. Thank you for answer.

**UPDATE**
I just do something like this.

```
var nameContact = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.nameContactText);
            nameContactText = nameContact.Text.ToString();
            var nameContactSummary = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameSummary);
            nameContactSummary.Text = nameContactText;
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to store data you need to transfer in parent activity (assuming that both fragments are hosted in the same activity) so every fragment will have access to this data using `(Activity as yourActivityType).YourPropertyName` in every fragment.

More details on Communicating with the Activity from Fragment can be found here:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: But you know in Xamarin you write in C#, not in Java, and there are some differences how to write your code.
I create something like this:

var inflate = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
View contactLayout = inflate.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AddContactLayout, null);
EditText nameContact = contactLayout.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.ID.nameContactText);
string nameContactText = nameContact.Text.ToString();

It crash my App when I go to 4th fragment.